# How to open outbound port using Azure cli?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, port, azure-cli

I have a Linux VM on Azure. I want to allow outbound traffic on some ports. For inbound, I have used this command on the Azure CLI.

```
az vm open-port --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myVM --port 80
```

Is there an equivalent Azure CLI command for opening outbound traffic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can open outbound ports using CLI. You need to open the outbound port in the Network Security Group. You can find the docs here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nsg/rule?view=azure-cli-latest

A sample command is

```
az network nsg rule create --name
                       --nsg-name
                       --priority
                       --resource-group
                       [--access {Allow, Deny}]
                       [--description]
                       [--destination-address-prefixes]
                       [--destination-asgs]
                       [--destination-port-ranges]
                       [--direction {Inbound, Outbound}]
                       [--protocol {*, Esp, Icmp, Tcp, Udp}]
                       [--source-address-prefixes]
                       [--source-asgs]
                       [--source-port-ranges]
                       [--subscription]
```